# How to manage nested relation in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails and trying to create an C2C marketplace App just to understand how rails works and start some real project later on.

The idea is that User can place Order to other User. Orders is related with user's Printer (you choice user where you want to print on /order page). Printer in its turn have many colors to print

For now, Im stack with very basic things.

**I want to display list of all printers with owner's name and colors available on /order page in Orders controller.** Thank you in advance for any ideas how I can do this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :printers, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :orders, dependent: :destroy
end


class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end


class Printer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates :model, presence: true, allow_nil: true

    has_many :materials, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Orders controller with index action (/orders)

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def index
  @printers = Printer.all
  end   
end
```

And index.html.erb

```
<% @printers.each do |p| %>
          <div class="col-xs-9">
            <div><%= "USERNAME HERE" %></div> <!--Do not know how to display parent's model here? -->
            <div><%= p.model %></div> <!--Works fine-->
            <div><%= p.colors.each do |c| c.color end  %></div> <!--Display array instead of strings-->
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <button>Order</button>
          </div>
<% end %>
```

Simplified schema.db

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160627132435) do

  create_table "colors", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "color"
    t.integer  "printer_id"
  end

  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "price"
    t.string   "status"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "printers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "model"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "printers", ["user_id"], name: "index_printers_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
  end

  add_foreign_key "orders", "users"
  add_foreign_key "printers", "users"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to do:

```
<% @printers.each do |p| %>
          <div class="col-xs-9">
            <div><%= p.user.first_name %></div> <!--Do not know how to display parent's model here? -->
            <div><%= p.model %></div> <!--Works fine-->
            <div><% p.colors.each do |c| 
              <%= c.color %>
            <% end  %></div> <!--Display array instead of strings-->
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <button>Order</button>
          </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you. The p.user.first_name works well. Quite easy ) But colors gives me this http://joxi.ru/a2XWXvZtMN4Nmg - any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Updated the answer for the fix

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for your help!